# How to lookup a resource in a Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I have Chef recipe where I want to lookup another resource that is defined by another recipe.

Reason for this it that I want to read one of its attributes and reuse the value.

I'm doing this is in a Chef zero run. In my recipe I am doing something like

```
myresource = resources(my_lwrp: "somename")
```

The `resources` collection however is empty.

I am not sure if this makes sense. But in that case, how should the `resources` collection be used? When is it not empty?

Comment: show your recipes (or a reproducible example) and say in which order they are in your runlist, if your resource does not appear in the resources collection, it's that it has not been evaluated at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely being hit by a compile vs. converge phase issue. http://coderanger.net/two-pass/ has some details on that. In general I wouldn't recommend this kind of indirect sharing via global variables. There is a reason that using globals is cliche-level bad coding :) It leads to unreadable and unmaintainable code. Try using a helper method shared between both locations instead.